# Does accuracy affect in-hand weapon sway or just how accurate bullets are?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've noticed there's two major factors that affect my accuracy; random spread of bullets *after* the leave the barrel, and the character physically swaying their weapon. Some weapons (notably SMGs) sway so much it's *painful* to operate them zoomed. Is this a function of accuracy or is weapon sway one of the hidden weapon stats? I can deal with inaccurate bullets (I use SMGs) but inaccurate *aiming* drives me insane.

I'm not talking about recoil (unless the stats are related), guns do this when aiming before firing as well.

If a gun has low accuracy, will it sway? If a gun sways, will it always have low "post barrel" accuracy as well?

Comment: This issue really puts me off wanting to play Borderlands 2 simply because I can't actually shoot anything.

Comment: @DavidYell different guns/manufacturers sway differently. If you avoid Hyperion most of the mid/late game guns don't actually sway that much. Not sure why they made them annoying at all though, especially at the start; not a good first impression

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Weapon stability is a hidden stat as it was in Borderlands.  Weapon modifiers can improve stability.  In fact apparently weapons have "accessories" now (you will see this on the weapon model though you might not recognize it).  As with Borderlands, you'll want to take guns out for a spin to see how they handle.  I believe can stocks help with stability, so if you see a gun with a stock take it for a whirl.  Obviously any scoped weapon will show off stability (or lack thereof), and Sniper Rifles are sort of the kings of this.

Accuracy is a separate stat from stability.  I do not know if there is a correlation between the two (and certainly can't speculate on the strength of that correlation).

Some manufacturers were known for making more stable weapons than others though I can't recall off hand who is known for what; keep that in mind.  Well, I remember that Tediore makes exploding, teleporting guns.

By the by, this [Borderlands 2 Wiki](http://www.bl2wiki.com/Borderlands_2_Wiki) seems the most developed so far.  It references stability in several places (including Pixel's link in the comments).  It's probably worth pointing out that all of the terms we use may not have the same meanings internally in the engine. Ben, that article about the Accuracy Pool in the comments doesn't seem to contradict what I wrote here, but may well be illustrating how externally we see one model of how things work but it's an abstraction.  I don't doubt that stability, recoil, and inherent accuracy interact in strange and mysterious ways in the code!

Comment: The Borderlands wiki seems conflicted on this; [this article implies it's correlated well with accuracy the stat](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Accuracy#Screen_effects) but from lots of reading the wiki in BL1 I really do think I remember talk of stability being a separate stat.

Comment: And IIRC Hyperion made super stable guns in BL1, and they're "autostabilizing" in BL2 (the longer you fire the more accurate they get)

Comment: The article detailing [weapon accessories](http://www.bl2wiki.com/Accessories) clearly states that the 'Stability' accessory will "help keep sway under control".

Comment: @pixel that's very helpful! If only I didn't have to remember 8 prefixes

Comment: @Ben Brocka - not following you there. The article you linked doesn't conflict with anything I wrote, and even suggests Stability is being used in at least one place.  Anyway, I was just coming to add the link Pixel posted.

Comment: That article does say that accuracy (or more directly the accuracy pool) factors in, though it sounds like there's a separate stat on top of that

Comment: Guessing wildly (but in a manner too sexy for this comment), it sounds to me like accuracy (and one assumes the gun and player accuracy bonuses are tracked separately), stability, and yes probably recoil all affect the accuracy pool (which is the base mechanic at work).

Answer (score 1):

Accuracy seems tied to sway. Pick up a weapon with a high initial crosshair bloom that increases accuracy as you fire. You'll notice that sway decreases as the crosshairs tighten up.

It looks like sway is a physical representation of crosshair bloom, and weapons with very wide crosshairs will also have high sway, while weapons with very tight crosshairs will have little sway. Test it out.