# What specific effect(s) does the borderlands 2 weapon modifier "increases weapon stability" have on a gun?

Tags: borderlands-2

I want to know the actual effect that the 'increases weapon stability' modifier, which appears to come from a Grip or pistol gunstock, has on a guns performance.  Does it just reduce pre-shot scope sway?  Does it reduce recoil while shooting?  Does it increase the speed a gun regains its accuracy after firing?  Does it have any impact on hip-fire performance?  Etc.

Is it one, some or all of the above, or something else entirely?

Very curious to know, and i appreciate any and all insight

Comment: In my experience it simply means that the gun only reaches the advertised accuracy score if you hold the trigger long enough. The first shots will kind of be all over the place.

Comment: @badp you are thinking of hyperion guns, they all have that property.  increased stability is something else

Comment: @spartacus yep and it's listed as a separate thing on the item card; I do believe I've seen Hyperion guns with both traits, listed separately

Answer (score 10):

According to the [Borderlands Wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Sniper_Rifle):

> Another important thing to take into account when choosing what sniper rifle is going to serve the best is an invisible quality known as stability. **Stability only becomes a factor when sighting a sniper rifle, and it is measured in how fast the weapon stops swaying when first sighted, between shots, and when the user takes damage.**

Comment: Yup, stability decreases the amount that the aiming reticule sways and swings around the place whilst zoomed. It's my personal favourite mod as it makes the game actually playable. There is a question about sway+accuracy. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84923/does-accuracy-affect-in-hand-weapon-sway-or-just-how-accurate-bullets-are